# Apache upload file /tmp permission denied

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos, server

I have centos 7 and i installed apache on it and changed document root to /home/morteza/development. Everything works, but when i want to upload a file it says:

> move_uploaded_file(/home/morteza/development/news/data/news/54f04fb97482820150227023633online10-16px.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/morteza/development/news/core/assist.php on line 110

I added apache user and group to /tmp and my website upload directory. Here is getfacl /tmp:

```
file: tmp
owner: root
group: root
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx 
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:apache:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::rwx
```

same for /home/morteza/development/news/data, where i want to upload files.
I used same php code on another servers and works fine. What is the problem here?

Additional: here is getsebool output for httpd:

```
httpd_anon_write --> off
httpd_builtin_scripting --> on
httpd_can_check_spam --> off
httpd_can_connect_ftp --> off
httpd_can_connect_ldap --> off
httpd_can_connect_mythtv --> off
httpd_can_connect_zabbix --> off
httpd_can_network_connect --> off
httpd_can_network_connect_cobbler --> off
httpd_can_network_connect_db --> off
httpd_can_network_memcache --> off
httpd_can_network_relay --> off
httpd_can_sendmail --> off
httpd_dbus_avahi --> off
httpd_dbus_sssd --> off
httpd_dontaudit_search_dirs --> off
httpd_enable_cgi --> on
httpd_enable_ftp_server --> off
httpd_enable_homedirs --> off
httpd_execmem --> off
httpd_graceful_shutdown --> on
httpd_manage_ipa --> off
httpd_mod_auth_ntlm_winbind --> off
httpd_mod_auth_pam --> off
httpd_read_user_content --> on
httpd_run_stickshift --> off
httpd_serve_cobbler_files --> off
httpd_setrlimit --> off
httpd_ssi_exec --> off
httpd_sys_script_anon_write --> off
httpd_tmp_exec --> off
httpd_tty_comm --> off
httpd_unified --> off
httpd_use_cifs --> off
httpd_use_fusefs --> off
httpd_use_gpg --> off
httpd_use_nfs --> off
httpd_use_openstack --> off
httpd_use_sasl --> off
httpd_verify_dns --> off
```

Comment: What are the permissions for the file /home/morteza/development/news/data/news/54f04fb97482820150227023633online10-16px.png ?

Comment: This file made by php from form. This file is a temporary file that php made.

Comment: Have you checked selinux status.??

Comment: I checked it. I enabled it. I also executed setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content 1. SeLinux status is enforcing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give PHP read/write permissions for the directory that you want to upload the file to. Normally in Linux-based system this user is called www-data.

You can check this using this PHP-script

```
<?php
    echo exec("whoami");
?>
```

Comment: And then add this user to the `/tmp` directory as you've done for `apache`

Comment: You could create a group for the directory, and add `apache` to this group by:

`useradd -G {group-name} username`

And then take recursive 

`chown -R :group-name /tmp`

Comment: chown change directory owner and i don't want to change /tmp owner. Instead i added apache user and apache group as owner using sefacl. But doesn't work.

Comment: you won't change the owner of the directory, only the group that owns the directory

Answer (score 0):

It was on selinux. I disabled selinux and it works now. But i don't now which config was the problem. For now i just disabled selinux and after restart it works. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem (user apache cannot write to /tmp on Centos 7). It seems that PHP is either reporting the wrong directory or there is kind of behind the scene redirection going on. The actual file gets written to:

`/var/tmp/systemd-private-73473abd844a4c4382e2e87952f1eb3b-httpd.service-2SNEIV/`

The owner of the directory was root (the alphanumeric part of the directory will probably be different for everyone):

`drwxrwxrwt  2 root root   6 Feb 22 20:58 tmp`

I changed the owner to apache:

`sudo chown -R apache /var/tmp/`

Which resulted in:

`drwxrwxrwt  2 apache root   6 Feb 22 20:58 tmp`

This is a brute for approach and I am still working on it, but I can now upload files via PHP.